# EntityMetadataWrapperException: unknown data property for field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have recently been trying to update my code to use entity wrappers to access field values. Now I have this:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("node", $nid);
print($wrapper->field_property_sample()->value());
```

instead of this:

```
print($node->field_property_sample[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"]);
```

The problem is sometimes I encounter this:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: unknown data property field_property_sample.

Is there a way for me to workaround this?

I have about 10 of these fields that can throw this exception and it is really getting ugly

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("node", $nid);

try {
  print($wrapper->field_property_sample()->value());
} catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException &e){
  print("");
}

/** repeat 10 times **/
```

Is there some function that I can more or less call like this?

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("node", $nid);
print($wrapper->field_property_sample->exists() ? $wrapper->field_property_sample->value()  : "" );

/** repeat 10 times **/
```

Answer (score 8):

Yep, you can just use existing features of the PHP language

```
try {
  print($wrapper->field_property_sample->value());
}
catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
  // Recover
}
```

Or, since `EntityMetadataWrapper` implements `__isset()` you can use that:

```
print isset($wrapper->field_property_sample) ? $wrapper->field_property_sample->value() : '';
```

Comment: That is what I am doing but when you have about 10 properties that can throw that exception the code gets real ugly real fast.

Comment: See the updated answer, plain old `isset()` is the cleanest way.

Comment: Tried this several times, it is still throwing the EntityMetadataWrapperException even with the isset() call. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 5):

With reference to Clive's answer, you can use `__isset()` like this:

```
print ($wrapper->__isset('field_property_sample') ? $wrapper->field_property_sample->value() : '';
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `isset($wrapper->field_property_sample)` instead of accessing the magic method `__isset` directly. If anything ever changes in the way that `__isset` can be implemented, just calling `isset()` will likely continue to work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

On nested field collections:

When iterating over a list of field collections, and checking for a non-empty field collection nested within the first, isset() does not work. However, I found that checking:

```
  foreach ($node_wrapper->field_fc_one AS $field_collection) {

    // Grab a nested field collection, properly wrapped.
    $nested_fc_wrapper = $field_collection->field_nested_fc;

    // isset() or $wrapper->__isset('') do not work here, but this does:
    if(nested_fc_wrapper->getIdentifier()) {

      // Do some stuff
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `field_property_sample()` doesn't make sense, because:

- `$wrapper->field_property_sample()` is used to call a **class method**
- `$wrapper->field_property_sample` is used to get a value of the **class property**

Property is the variable which you want to use, class method is the function which you want to call.

So using:

```
$wrapper->field_property_sample->value();
```

is the correct syntax.

For proper usage of Entity metadata wrappers, check: [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) page.

Here is some code example:

```
try {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $wrapper->field_property_sample = 'some data';
  $wrapper->field_multi_sample = array('1st', '2nd');
  $wrapper->save();
}
catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
  watchdog_exception('my_module', $e);
}
```

To print, use:

```
print($wrapper->field_property_sample->value());
```

or [`dpm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7.x-1.x), [`dd()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7.x-1.x) from Devel module.