# Entity Meta data Wrapper Exception

Tags: drupal-7

I try to create a E-commerce website in drupal 7. I'm using commerce module and then adding the product but it's not displaying the product. Some errors are shown below, how to fix them?

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property commerce_product. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 335 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Islandmaids\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc). Backtrace:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal EntityMetadataWrapperException workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329870/drupal-entitymetadatawrapperexception-workaround)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a debugging Tool like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). There are many tutorials to integrate debugging software into IDEs.

After the installation of the debugger you should set a breakpoint to the line 335 in

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Islandmaids\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc

and watch which values are passed to functions or maybe which custom module is in the call-stack. With this information you can go deeper into the code by setting more breackpoints.